# How to safely use dell latitude without battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, dell-latitude

I was following a YouTube video and managed to remove the battery including tapes. However, the videos on youtube mostly show how to replace the battery but I do not have a replacement and plan to use laptop on AC power instead.

However, I do not know if I need to further remove the tapes on the laptop and what orientation should the remaining parts have before I screw the cover back on?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Video link I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwJcjgBRl10

[image: Stuck here]

[image: Disconnected wire]

Comment: I'd check it will even boot without the battery before worrying about whether to put bits of sticky tape back. That really is one messy bit of design though - I've never seen anything quite so cobbled-together. Gave me a good laugh with my morning coffee ;))

Comment: Many laptops cannot function without a battery, so a test is indeed indicated.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the heads up! It works thankfully. I'm using it now without the cover, but there is a piece of wire jutting out. The wire was previously attached to the battery, but I pulled it out when i followed the youtube video on battery replacement. However, I need help figuring out how to flatten it in the right orientation before I slap the cover back on because Im worried misorientation could somehow interfere with the circuit connectivity. Do yall have any ideas on whether the orientation matters?

Comment: Also, upon disconnecting the battery, i read (https://www.groovypost.com/tips/run-laptop-without-battery-safe/) that there may be chance of overheating without a battery since laptop might draw too much power from ac supply. Any warning signs to look out for when using laptop on AC to prevent fried components? Thank you very much. I have also edited the question to include the video link.

Comment: Some laptops will run at half speed without a battery, to prevent overheating & sudden crashes. You'd be better off overall to just bite the bullet & get a new battery… I put one in mine just yesterday - a *'mere'* £100 but it'll extend its life by several years.

Comment: Bear in mind that some modern CPUs rated at "35W TDP" can actually have a short term power rating up at 100W. (See https://hothardware.com/news/intel-12th-gen-alder-lake-mobile-cpu-power-limits-revealed) What that means is that without the battery to take up slack your power brick may well be completely insufficient to take up surges and changes in demand. If you have a 45W or 60W power brick for your laptop you may find that it randomly turns off unless your firmware has a way to disable enhanced power modes. As mentioned by others this might mean your processor speed becomes limited.

Comment: +1 one for being so brave and diving in!  That is how most of us learned.. but know that most of us have bricked *something* at least once along the way.